# How could I get code of the application deployed on digital ocean?

Tags: github, meteor, digital-ocean

I need to edit application developed by somebody else in Meteor.js deployed on Digitalocean. I have an access to digitalocean account, but have no idea how to access code and the whole folder where is application stored. Is this even possible ? Should I ask him for github repo with the app to get it instead ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Ask for the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for the repo. The server may only contain the built version of the app (since that's all that's needed to run it) and that's no good for developing. You can't edit that directly.